git svn checkout, any other ways workaround this?
I am  trying to import a sub-directorry from github.
The answer form this question said git checkout will work. However, I have to use
git svn

But there is no git svn checkout available in git svn. What should I do?

Which answer, specifically? there are 46 Answers (btw you can link to a specific one by clicking the Share button and copying the link). But yes, git has now sunsetted subversion support. As an alternative, this answer using --filter and sparse-checkout looks like it would be worth a try.
